# Can Intellij display package tests separately while in package view?

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea, package

I have java source files in /src/main/java/mypackage and tests for them in /src/test/java/mypackage. When in package view, Intellij displays these files all together, since they are technically the same package. I would like them to appear separately. I have tried a few configuration options with no luck.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions for this.

Comment: I've had a good look, and I can't see how such a thing would be possible. If you choose the `Folders Always On Top` option the classes are sorted with all tests grouped together following the production classes, but that's as close as I could get.

Comment: This is a shame, really.

Answer (score 3):

I think that Andrii solution is the best but if you want to use package view, you can split types inner package checking "Sort by Type" option in menu.

[image: Sort by type option]
[image: Result displayed]

Answer (score 1):

Switching to project view fixed it for me. 
I was accidentally on Package View before.
Click the drop down to change.

[image]

I know the OP explicitly says "while in package view", but others might find this hint useful.

Answer (score 0):

[Is IntelliJ developers decision](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206921645-Test-sources-mixed-in-with-main-source-folders?page=1#community_comment_207063829) to "mix" them, because technically `src` and `test` share the same package structure although they are different directories, so there is no option to get the same view as Eclipse does.

What I do is creating new test packages so it looks like this:

```
/src/main/java/mypackage/

/src/test/java/mypackage/testunit

/src/test/java/mypackage/testintegration
```

Comment: By doing so you will have to keep all your classes/methods public, otherwise they won't be accessible from another package.

Answer (score 0):

I believe 'Android' view - the one from 'Project', 'Packages' etc. - will give you the behavior you're looking for. Since IntelliJ supports Android development out-of-the-box, this view is present by default.

Here is how my project looks. Note different folders `java` and `tests`.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

What I recommend is not putting the tests in your src folder, but rather in a separate folder.  This will result in:

`/src/main/java/mypackage`

`/tst/main/java/mypackage`

which you can mark separately as source and test.